# Blue Prism Error - Internal : The specified item was not locked by this business object

Tags: blueprism, rpa

When I am executing Mark Exception Action stage(Work Queue - Mark Exception) then I am getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is simple - the item that you're trying to update with new status is not locked by your process.

That could happen in many, many ways. For example:

- The item was already updated
- The item ID was overwritten with some different item ID
- The previous item has been marked as exception, and the process received a new item id, but it has not been locked. You cannot update a new item, because it has not been locked at the start of the process.
- The item has been deferred and that action unlocks item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the business object `Work Queue`'s action `Get Next Item` in order to *lock* the current item. Only *lock*ed items can be marked as *Exception*.

[image: Get Next Item]

Answer (score -1):

Before marking as exception, you just need to update the status and while marking exception there is one input parameter called  `keep locked` need to set false

[image]